# Store data in a vector in a for loop: why the vector "apari" is still NULL?

Tags: r

```
set.seed(0)
a<-round(runif(20,1,50), digits=0)
apari<-c()

is.pari<-function(a){ 
    for (i in 1: length (a)){
        if((a[i]%%2)==0){ 
            apari<-c( apari, a[i]) 
            #print (a[i])
        }
    }
    return(apari)
}
is.pari(a)
apari
```

I tried different ways to have the results in the vector "apari", but every time it is NULL.
It's correctly displayed but not written.
It's correctly returned by the function, but not written also if I create it with the vector (...) function.

Comment: Ciao Mora! Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: Hi Mora, please do not post screenshots of code. Rather copy and paste the code. We are not going to type this out on our end.

Comment: In your code, you assign `apari` as `apari <- c()` then write and run a function, but you dont change `apari` at all. So then at the bottom when you call `apari` it will of course return `NULL` since you haven't modified it at all. Do you mean `apari <- is.pari(a)`?

Comment: FYI your entire function can be simplified by `a[a %% 2 == 0]`, no need for a function or loop. Try running the test for equality with `all.equal(is.pari(a), a[a %% 2 == 0])` and you will see it is `TRUE`. Growing vectors inside a `for` loop is not generally good practice. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're updating `apari` within a local environment (inside the function), but when the function ends, you're then trying to find the value of `apari` in the global environment, where it hasn't changed.

Here's a few options:

1. (simplest, easy to debug) - run `apari <- is.pari(a)`
2. (harder to debug, but would mean that running`is.pari(a)` would change the value of `apari`) - change `apari<-c( apari, a[i])` to `apari <<- c( apari, a[i])`. `<<-` changes the value of a variable in the global environment. The warning with this is, in a long script, it can then be hard then to keep track of what variables actually mean in your code
3. (best option if you don't care about keeping the function as is) - use `a[a %% 2 == 0]` instead, as [jpsmith mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76930115/store-data-in-a-vector-in-a-for-loop-why-the-vector-apari-is-still-null/76930260#comment135617863_76930115).